# Updating a Fortran variable by addition

Tags: fortran

In my Fortran code I need to update many variables by adding something to them. For example, if `x` is my variable, I may need to do something like this:

```
x = x + 1
```

The problem is that my variables are array elements and have big names etc so repeating `x` in the above equation is cumbersome task. In Python for example we have the `+=` operator to achieve this. Do we have something similar in Fortran?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, Fortran does not have this operator. However, you could implement a subroutine to do so:

```
elemental subroutine my_incr( var, incr )
  implicit none
  integer,intent(inout) :: var
  integer,intent(in)    :: incr

  var = var + incr
end subroutine
```

Then you could call that in your code:

```
! ...
call my_incr( x, 1 )
! ...
```

Due to the `elemental` nature of the subroutine, you can also perform this operation on arrays:

```
! ...
call my_incr( array(:), 1 )
! ...
```

Comment: Any reason for FORTRAN not having this useful operator?

Comment: Personally I'd write `call my_incr( array, 1 )`  rather than `call my_incr( array(:), 1 )` since `array(:)` is technically an array slice  and Fortran may make a copy of the whole array to the slice and pass that copy to the subroutine.  This is less likely to happen if the whole array is passed unsliced.

Comment: One of the reasons is it is not an operator, or it wouldn't be in Fortran. Fortran's assignment (`=`) is NOT an operator. The `+=` would have to be defined like a completely new beast with new rules. FWIW there are proposals, for solving this, but they look different, what I saw was to introduce a special symbol for the left hand side of the assignment so that it could be referenced on the right-hand side.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I agree, this was just for demonstrating that `arr` really is an array ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> "The problem is that my variables are array elements and have big names etc so repeating x in the above equation is cumbersome task."

Well, if this is your only problem then the simplest and cleanest solution is to use the `associate` construct (I use it all the time for exactly this purpose):

```
ASSOCIATE( x => variable_with_really_long_name, &
           y => another_one)

    ! some calculations here

    x = x + 1

    ! some calculations here again

end associate
```