# Increment in Fortran

Tags: c++, fortran

I need to rewrite some code from C++ into FORTRAN. Most of the code is done, but I have one problem. I need to translate this C++:

```
A[B[c]++] = i;
```

into FORTRAN.

Comment: What is A, what is B, what is c and what i? It could mean anything, especially in C++ where operator overloading is so popular.

Comment: You will need to define what A, B, c and i are in types. As it is now, this code is somewhat nonsensical: `B[c]` is a temporary value, and post-increment (`++`) doesn't make sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating the variable by addition in fortran](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305323/updating-the-variable-by-addition-in-fortran)

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ: `B[c]` is usually an lvalue , even with operator overloading (e.g. vector::operator[]`)

Comment: It's equivalent to `A[B[c]] = i; B[c] = B[c] + 1;` (Assuming plain arrays and numeric types.)

Answer (score 2):

That's a doosy of a statement. I believe it is using c to index into array B, then using that value to index into array A, and assigning that a value of i. Then it increments the value in array B. Should be equivalent to the following:

```
A(B(c)) = i
B(c) = B(c) + 1
```

but the order may be reversed (I'm not sure whether the value in array B is incremented before or after the index into array A in that context in C++).